# Постраничный Title

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Решил подучить php и столкнулся с проблемой. Есть класс

```
<?php 
    abstract class Core_Admin{
        protected function get_header(){
            include "header.php";
        }
        protected function get_header_menu(){
                    echo'
                    <header>
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
                      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                      </button>
                      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

                      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    ';
                    echo'
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon ion-plus-round"></i>New</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a href="?do=add_statti" class="dropdown-item">Post</a>
                            <a href="?do=add_menu" class="dropdown-item">Menu</a>
                            <a href="?do=add_category" class="dropdown-item">Category</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    ';

                    echo'
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon ion-person"></i>User</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a href="?do=user_groups" class="dropdown-item">User Groups</a>
                            <a href="?do=?do=roles_add" class="dropdown-item">Add Roles</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    ';


                    echo'
                        </ul>
                        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </form>
                      </div>
                    </nav>
                </header><div class="container"><div class="row">';


        }
        protected function get_menu(){
                    echo'<div class="col-sm-3">';

                    get_some();
                    echo'<nav>
                    <ul class="nav flex-column">

                        <a class="list-group-item" href="?do=edit_statti">Posts</a>


                        <a class="list-group-item" href="?do=edit_menu">Menu</a>


                        <a class="list-group-item" href="?do=edit_category">Category</a>
                    </ul></nav>
                    ';

                    echo'</div>';


        }
        public function get_footer(){

            include 'footer.php';
        }
        public function get_body(){
            if($_GET['admin'])
                $this->glob();
            if($_POST || $_GET['del'] || $_GET['update_menu']){
                $this->obr();
            }
            $this->get_header();
            $this->get_header_menu();
            $this->get_menu();
            $this->get_content();
            $this->get_footer();
        }
        abstract function get_content();
        protected function get_categories(){
            $link = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
            if (!$link){
                echo("error");
            }
            else{
                $query="SELECT id_category,name_category FROM category";
                $result=mysqli_query($link, $query);

                if (!$result) {
                    exit(mysqli_error($link ));
                }
                else{
                    $row=array();
                    for ($i=0; $i < $result->num_rows; $i++) { 
                        $row[] = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

                    }
                    return $row;
                }
            }
            mysqli_close($link);
        }
        protected function get_text_statti($id){
            $link = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
            if (!$link){
                echo("error");
            }
            else{
                $query="SELECT id,title,img_src,discription,text,cat FROM statti WHERE id='$id'";
                $result=mysqli_query($link, $query);

                if (!$result) {
                    exit(mysqli_error($link ));
                }
                else{
                    $row=array();
                        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    return $row;
                }
            }
            mysqli_close($link);
        }
        protected function get_text_menu($id){
            $link = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
            if (!$link){
                echo("error");
            }
            else{
                $query="SELECT id_menu,name_menu,text_menu FROM menu WHERE id_menu='$id'";
                $result=mysqli_query($link, $query);

                if (!$result) {
                    exit(mysqli_error($link ));
                }
                else{
                    $row=array();
                        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    return $row;
                }
            }
            mysqli_close($link);
        }
        protected function get_text_category($id){
            $link = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
            if (!$link){
                echo("error");
            }
            else{
                $query="SELECT id_category,name_category FROM category WHERE id_category='$id'";
                $result=mysqli_query($link, $query);

                if (!$result) {
                    exit(mysqli_error($link ));
                }
                else{
                    $row=array();
                        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    return $row;
                }
            }
            mysqli_close($link);
        }
        protected function get_text_user_roles($id){
            $link = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
            if (!$link){
                echo("error");
            }
            else{
                $query="SELECT roles_id,roles_name FROM user_roles WHERE roles_id='$id'";
                $result=mysqli_query($link, $query);

                if (!$result) {
                    exit(mysqli_error($link ));
                }
                else{
                    $row=array();
                        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    return $row;
                }
            }
            mysqli_close($link);
        }
    }
?>
```

И его дочерний класс

```
<?php
    class admin extends Core_Admin{
        protected function glob(){
            $mlpr="admin";
        }
        public function get_content(){
            echo '<div class="col-sm-9">';
            if ($_SESSION['res']) {
                echo $_SESSION['res'];
                unset($_SESSION['res']);
            }
            $link = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
            if (!$link){
                echo("error");
            }
            else{
                $query="SELECT id,title FROM statti";
                $result=mysqli_query($link, $query);
                if (!$result) {
                    exit(mysqli_error($link ));
                }

                else{
                    $row=array();
                    echo'
       <div class="card mb-5">
           <div class="card-header">News</div>
           <div class="card-block p-0">
               <table class="table table-bordered table-sm m-0">
                   <thead class="">
                       <tr>
                           <th>#</th>
                           <th>Title</th>
                           <th>Delete</th>
                       </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>';
                    for ($i=0; $i < $result->num_rows; $i++) {
                        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                        printf('
                           <tr>
                               <td>%s</td>
                               <td><a href="?do=update_statti&id_text=%s">%s</a></td>
                               <td><a class="badge badge-default" href="?do=delete_statti&del=%s">&#x274C;</a></td>
                           </tr>
                           ',$row['id'],$row['id'],$row['title'],$row['id']);
                    }
                    echo' </tbody>
               </table>
           </div>

       </div>';
                }
            }
            mysqli_close($link);



            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Никак не могу передать значение из дочернего класса в header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        <?php echo $mlpr ?>
    </title>
<?php 

    $css_fold = 'css/';
    $js_fold = 'js/';
    $css_files= scandir($css_fold);
    $js_files= scandir($js_fold);
    echo'<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>';
    echo'<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>';

    foreach ($js_files as $js_file) {
            if ($js_file!='jquery-3.2.1.min.js' && $js_file!='popper.min.js') {
                if(preg_match('/\.(js)/', $js_file)){
                echo'<script src="js/'.$js_file.'"></script>';
            }
        }

    }
    foreach ($css_files as $css_file) {
        if(preg_match('/\.(css)/', $css_file)){
            echo'<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/'.$css_file.'">';
        }
    }

?>
</head>
<body>
```

Может кто поможет с реализацией. Да, я новичок :D

Comment: боюсь даже спрашивать где вас учили так код писать. дочитал ровно до `echo "<header>"`, хотя следовало остановится еще на `include "header.php";`. Дальше читать - глаза ломать и глубокую душевную травму от говнокода получать

Comment: Может проще с помощью **js**? `document.title = "Some new title text";`

Comment: teran, откуда столько негатива? Я просил помочь, а если не в состоянии идите лесом глаза ломать и глубокую душевную травму от говнокода получать

Comment: да я просто не понимаю, откуда вы все берете эту дикую манеру мешанины html и пхп кода. никогда, никогда не мешайте мух с котлетами. не начинайте даже писать так код, выкидывайте и сжигайте книги, в которых такие примеры. с таким подходом вы не научитесь ничему толковому. это отвратительная практика. логика должна быть в одном месте, представление в другом. инклуд файлов внутри функций это тоже адище

Comment: тут просто кладезь того как не надо программировать на пхп.

Comment: 1) Советую вам вызубрить PSR-1 и PSR-2.

Comment: 2) Писать HTML-код в PHP-классах - плохо.